# Why is this PyGTK menu empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pygtk

I am working on a PyGTK application with a `Gtk.Toolbar`. One of the items in taht toolbar is a `Gtk.MenuToolButton`. However, clicking on the arrow once the program runs results in an empty menu (a tiny white sliver). Here is the code that sets up the menu:

```
                self.compileMenu = Gtk.Menu()
                self.defaultCompileOption = Gtk.MenuItem(label = "Compile with defaults")
                self.configCompileOption = Gtk.MenuItem(label = "Change compile options...")
                self.compileWithFiles = Gtk.MenuItem(label = "Bundle files...")
                
                self.compileMenu.append(self.defaultCompileOption)
                self.compileMenu.append(self.configCompileOption)
                self.compileMenu.append(self.compileWithFiles)
                
                self.compileButton = Gtk.MenuToolButton(icon_name = "x-package-repository", label = "Compile...", menu = self.compileMenu)
```

There is also a call to `self.toolbar.add` at the bottom, to add the `MenuToolButton` to the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! Turns out that for some reason you need to call, in my case, `compileMenu.show_all()` to make it realize that you added things to it.